# React Native Navigation Error - Unable to resolve module `@react-navigation/stack`

Tags: react-native

Since I've been recently made aware of React Navigation, I tried using it, but I can't get it to work.

I've followed the instructions presented at the documents of reactnavigation.org, normally, with npm. Since that didn't work, I also tried installing via their yarn commands, but the same error was presented.

While I couldn't find any answer to this same problem, since apparently it was `react-navigation-stack` instead of `@react-navigation/stack`, I tried out solutions for similar errors - trying to install it with `--save`and trying to reinstall `react-navigation`, rebuild the project, then restart the packager with `react-native-start`.

The relevant part of the error reads as this:

> The development server returned response error code: 500
>
> URL:
>   http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false
>
> Body:
>   {"originModulePath":"App.js","targetModuleName":"@react-navigation/stack;","message":"Unable
>   to resolve module `@react-navigation/stack;` from `App.js`:
>   @react-navigation/stack; could not be found within the project.

Alternatively, I also tried using react-navigation-stack by following old setup tutorials, but I couldn't get that version to work either. I'd much prefer using something up-to-date, though.

Comment: Which version of react-native are you using?

Comment: are you using expo to run your app ? or browser ?

Comment: attach your package.json file here

Comment: Try install ```@react-navigation/stack``` using ```npm install @react-navigation/stack``` or ```yarn add @react-navigation/stack```. If not follow the react-navigation installation guideline - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installation

Comment: Solved, it was a misplaced semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

I went to code as soon as I woke up and immediatly identified the problem, it was a semicolon.

Instead of `import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";`, I'd written `import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack;"` so yeah. Silly problem.